# SQL Server Convert String to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am having an issue converting 2PM to a date.

This code fails:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2018/10/23 14:00:00')
```

with this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

However, this code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2018/10/23 09:55:03')
```

works fine.

Why?

Comment: Your code works fine in rextester:  https://rextester.com/PYNX12435.  You probably just have a bad character in the string.

Comment: Why use a localized string in the first place? Why not pass a datetime parameter or an ISO8601 string (ie '2018-10-23T95:55:03')? That strings is affected by the server's language and date settings.

Comment: it works fine in MS SQL server 2014 , 2008 . what is the version of SQL server that you are using now ?

Comment: If you *have* to use that string at least use `PARSE` with a culture parameter that matches the string's culture

Comment: @MarianNasry that's just chance - that's a locale-specific format so it's interpreted based on the local `DATEFORMAT` settings. Set it to `dmy` for example and the conversion fails. `2018-10-23T09:55:03` though works no matter the `DATEFORMAT`

Comment: you have to send the string parameter format as SQL sever format ,i think.

Comment: @MarianNasry there's no "SQL server format". All strings are parsed using a specific locale *except* the unseparated date and the ISO8601 format.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In case you weren't aware: [Rextester has officially been hacked. Where do we go from here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375602/1115360) and there has been no information that I am aware of from the owner of the site that it has been reinstalled rather than patched, so it *could* still be compromised.

Comment: @AndrewMorton . . . That is a good point.  How about db<>fiddle instead.

Answer (score 1):

`DATETIME` in SQL Server has a tendency to be extremely picky about what string format can be converted into it. The best way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601** date format that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

So try these statements:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-10-23T14:00:00')
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-10-23T09:55:03')
```

do they both work?

Or if you use SQL Server **2008 or newer**, make use of the new `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!); then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible